# Múltiplas regras de Rewrite com .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, htaccess

Tenho o seguinte .htaccess atualmente:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## Esconder .PHP
    # Redirecionamento externo de /dir/foo.php para /dir/foo
        RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
        RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=302,L]

    # Redirecionamento interno de /dir/foo para /dir/foo.php
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
        RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]


## Redirecionamento para o parametro P do GET na index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?p=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

# Esconder a palavra "index"
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.*)index($|\ |\?)
    RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Agora eu tenho que passar um parametro para uma das páginas que já é acessada  pela regra do `index.php?p=$1` que no caso existe e funciona no URL:

```
www.site.com.br/portfolio?trabalho=14
```

Agora preciso mesclar as regras para conseguir acessar o url acima a partir de:

```
www.site.com.br/portfolio/14
```

É possível? Podem me ajudar?

Grato!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Voce pode adicionar o código abaixo logo após o bloco # Redirecionamento

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?p=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

Assim voce estará pegando o segundo parâmetro após a barra e o php vai receber na variavél get id ($_GET['id'])